# How to make Tun module running at linux start

Tags: tun

i installed Tun using:

```
modprobe tun
```

then did:

```
lsmod | grep tun
tun                    83840  0
```

Please how to make Tun running at reboot?

This is written on Hamachi website:

```
...Then add tun to the list of modules by using your favorite text editor and Create /etc/modules-load.d/tun.conf 

#Load tun module at boot.
tun
```

But this folder foes not exist in my /etc

Is it wise to add line "modprobe tun" into /etc/rc.local ?

Comment: Why do you need it running at reboot?  What tool are you using that isn't auto-loading it as needed?

Comment: Some person requested it, and i assigned it to his virtual machine (openvz)

Comment: I assume you have seen this page?  http://openvz.org/VPN_via_the_TUN/TAP_device. It has some suggestions

Comment: Yes, but i have not found on how to autostart it on boot.

Comment: You saw the line that said `To make sure that tun module will be automatically loaded on every reboot you can also add it or into /etc/modules.conf (on RHEL see /etc/sysconfig/modules/ directory`?  Since you are using Centos the RHEL setting probably applies to you.

Comment: in the /etc/sysconfig/modules im unsure what should be the filecontent to properly load Tun

Comment: i just need to start it (modprobe tun)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a file named /etc/modules ?
If yes, you can edit to add tun there

For CentOS check this out
http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-kernel-modules-persistant.html

Execute these 2 commands will create the rc.modules with command to load the tun module at startup

```
echo modprobe tun >> /etc/rc.modules
chmod +x /etc/rc.modules
```

Comment: no, it is not there, nor file, nor directory. There is no file modu* in /etc

Comment: What linux are you using?

Comment: centos 5.x 64 is the OS

Comment: Check the link in my answer

Comment: thx Wutiphong, i had no file /etc/rc.modules (only rc.local) so i executed that commands and now i see:


lrwxrwxrwx  - rc.local -> rc.d/rc.local    ;                                         
-rwxr-xr-x  - rc.modules    ; is that correct?

Comment: You can execute 2 command in the edited answer.

Comment: You need to change the module name after modprobe to tun

Comment: thx, i did above commands so my rc.modules contains line: modprobe tun  . but im unsure what you mean by changing the module name..

Comment: In the example the module name is "foo" so I mean change it to tun